# is it possible to dynamically add routes to the NGINX load balancer?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

Is it possible to manage routes in Nginx server dynamically, add and remove them, without stopping it from work, something like a circuit breaker (turn on / turn off) ? (the most closest analogy, I've found is Istio in Kubernetes, that allows to do that) (If this functionality is available within some other Software, please mention it down below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes **Nginx** supports the circuit breaker option but it's in Nginx **plus** mode.

Ref article : https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-reference-architecture-nginx-circuit-breaker-pattern/

Apart of that many other service mesh are available who support it as you mentioned Istio, LinkerD etc.

i would recommend checking the Traefik proxy which also supports and it's open source : https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/circuitbreaker/

If you are also familiar with the **Kong** you can also extend it and install the circuit breaker plugin into and use it.

Plugin example: https://github.com/dream11/kong-circuit-breaker

Checkout my article to how to extend the Kong with custom plugins and use it : https://faun.pub/building-kong-custom-docker-image-add-a-customized-kong-plugin-2157a381d7fd

Comment: please feel free to reach out if get stuck anywhere, Kong with a circuit breaker it looks a pretty good idea to extend the ingress controller. do share your output if you successful make it out and issues faced.